# Fuzzy query in kdb table

Tags: kdb

Created below table:

```
    Id   name    class
    1    adcvs    2
    2    adxcg    4
    3    adcbfgf  31
    4    adcbfgr  34
    5    adcbfgy  23
    6    adcbfgo  12
```

And now I want to get all columns which the `name` column contain the value `adcbfg`. i used the query :`` select from table where name in `adcbfg* ``, please give advice what question of my query.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a symbol is just a reference to a string you can't use a regular expression function on without dereferencing them first to get the underlying string. This is why using `` `adcbfg* `` didn't work.

For this same reason using a comparison operator between a string regular expression and the sym such as `name="adcbfg*"` will not work because they are different types.

The `like` command that JejeBelfort suggested allows you to use regular expressions on both strings and symbols, as with symbols it will dereference it first before applying the regular expression.

Although it might seem more complicated than just using a string, as symbol types are fixed-width it makes lookups faster than using variable-width strings

For more information on regular expressions see https://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/regex/

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `like` to perform this:

Create your table:

```
table:([]Id:1+til 6;name:`adcvs`adxcg`adcbfgf`adcbfgr`adcbfgy`adcbfgo;class:2 4 31 34 23 12)

Id name    class
----------------
1  adcvs   2    
2  adxcg   4    
3  adcbfgf 31   
4  adcbfgr 34   
5  adcbfgy 23   
6  adcbfgo 12
```

Then parse for the rows for which the `name` follows the pattern `adcbfg`:

```
select from table where name like "adcbfg*"

Id name    class
----------------
3  adcbfgf 31   
4  adcbfgr 34   
5  adcbfgy 23   
6  adcbfgo 12
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to use `like` could be:

```
table[where(table`name)like"adcbfg*"]
```

This would use less memory, but would take a bit longer to compute.

Also, more details and examples on the `like` keyword can be found on the KX site here:

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/strings/#like

http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/regex/